# Calling the result of a form select in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I'm creating a form for my incremental game which allows you to choose how many protons, neutrons, and electrons are in an atom. The code for selecting how many protons is here:

```
<select class="form-control" id="protons_in_atom">
<option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
</select>
```

I also have a button:

```
<button id="atom_creator" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create your atom!</button>
```

On the click, it executes these lines of code:

```
document.getElementById("atom_creator").onclick = function () {
    player.temp_protons_in_atom = document.getElementById("protons_in_atom");
    return alert(player.temp_protons_in_atom);
};
```

Unfortunately, what I receive is: [object HTMLSelectElement]
How do I cause player.temp_protons_in_atom to equal the option chosen?

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1085810/1576996) what you want? (Getting the selected value from a dropdown)

Comment: Could you add that as an answer so I can choose it as the best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1085810/1576996) link out. It details how to get the value of the selected option.

```
 document.getElementById("atom_creator").onclick = function () {
     temp = document.getElementById("protons_in_atom");
     player.temp_protons_in_atom = temp.options[temp.selectedIndex].text;

 };
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
player.temp_protons_in_atom
```

is the select/dropbox itself, to get the selected opinion use this:

```
return alert(player.temp_protons_in_atom.options[player.temp_protons_in_atom.selectedIndex].text);
```

Refrence is [this answear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/how-to-get-the-selected-value-of-dropdownlist-using-javascript/1085810#1085810).